# Enable SSL for specific context-path in Karaf Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, apache-karaf, jetty-9

I have a jax-rs service deployed in Karaf container v4.2.3 with jetty v9.4.12 and the service is deployed under /services context-path as shown in the picture.

[image]

I have managed to enable ssl client auth in Karaf Jetty but the problem is that it enables it globally which causes system console to become inaccessible.

Here is the config I used in org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg

```
org.osgi.service.http.enabled=false

org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true
org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true
org.osgi.service.http.port.secure=8443
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore=./etc/keystores/server-keystore.p12
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.truststore=etc/keystores/server-truststore.p12
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.truststore.password=secret
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.key.password=secret
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore.password=secret
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthneeded=true
```

Is it possible to have SSL client auth only for the /services path and leave system console on non-ssl (http) ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 ports or connectors configured. (one with SSL/TLS one without)

Then set the `/services/*` url-pattern to have a CONFIDENTIAL (servlet) constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at the moment I have http on port 8181 and https on 8443 both running at the same time for all the urls. How to I configure to /services/* url to go through the https port? Any example you can add or direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the default connectors, it is possible to configure additional connectors in the `etc/jetty.xml` configuration file.

The etc/jetty.xml is a standard Eclipse Jetty configuration file. The default Apache Karaf WebContainer etc/jetty.xml contains:

```
<!-- Use this connector for many frequently idle connections and for
    threadless continuations. -->
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host">
                <Property name="jetty.host" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="port">
                <Property name="jetty.port" default="8181" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Configure Authentication Realms -->
<!-- Realms may be configured for the entire server here, or -->
<!-- they can be configured for a specific web app in a context -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
```

The `SelectChannelConnector` defines the default connector of the WebContainer.

This connector defines the 8181 port number for the HTTP protocol (port property), and the 8443 port number for the HTTPS protocol (confidentialPort property).

The following resources give you details about advanced etc/jetty.xml configurations:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL

Comment: [wiki.eclipse.org is for Jetty 7 and Jetty 8, both of which are EOL (End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html).  Also, the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` class no longer exists in current versions of Jetty.

Comment: Oh my bad! There is `ServerConnector` you can refer to https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-ssl.html